# Función anónima asignada a una variable

Tags: javascript

Tengo la siguiente función anónima que no me devuelve  el resultado. Hay algún error?

```js
var sumar = function(){
 var calcular = 1 + 3;
    return calcular; 
};
    
document.write(sumar);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Primero no es una funcion anomina. Las funciones anonimas no tienen identificador para ser ejecutadas luego y esta sí (el identificador es `sumar`).

Y tienes que ejecutar la funcion para que te retorne:

```js
var sumar = function(){
    var calcular = 1 + 3;
        return calcular;    
    };
    
document.write(sumar()); // ejecutas el metodo sumar();
```

Solo para aclarar dudas. Esto seria una funcion anonima:

```js
(function(){
  console.log("hola mundo");
})();
```

No hay forma de que puedas mostrar hola mundo otra vez porque no tiene identificador.